# How to increase count if function called by another function in Python

Tags: python, function, token, nltk, counter

I am trying to count all tokens given by func1 and print out the result from func2. The problem is that each time func2 gets called the counter does not update for natural reasons because we call the function over and over again. Are there any ways of solving this? **NOTE**: only func2 is supposed to be changed

```
import nltk

def func1(tokens):
    listOfTokens = tokens.split()
    for token in listOfTokens:
        func2(token)

def func2(token):
    count = 0
    nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(token)
    count += len(nltk_tokens)
    print(count) # expected to be 4 but is printing : 1 1 1 1

func1("A b c d")
```

Comment: because count is local to `func2` so it does not remember its previous value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
import nltk

count = 0
def func1(tokens):
    listOfTokens = tokens.split()
    for token in listOfTokens:
        func2(token)

def func2(token):
    global count
    nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(token)
    count += len(nltk_tokens)
    print(count) # expected to be 4 but is printing : 1 1 1 1

func1("A b c d")
```

Comment: Thank you! Im sorry for not making it clear... func1 cannot be changed!

Comment: @TheRi Made the edit, now check

Comment: I see! Is it possible to only get the 4 without 1, 2, 3?

Comment: To print only 4 you need to write your print statement outside `func2` then it will print(4).  in your case write `print(count)` below this line `func1("A b c d")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass all tokens to func2 and make the counting.

```
def func1(tokens):
    listOfTokens = tokens.split()
    func2(listOfTokens)

def func2(listOfTokens):
    count = 0
    for token in listOfTokens:
        nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(token)
        count += len(nltk_tokens)
    print(count) # expected to be 4 but is printing : 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: yes, this will work. However, I am not allowed to change func1 for some odd reasons